# LEFT JOIN with where clause only for second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
1. posts (id, title, content, etc)
2. post_meta (id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
```

I want to get with only one query, all the entries from posts and the entries from post_meta only with post_meta='x'. Some of the entries from posts doesn't have correspondent in post_meta, but I need them. I can do this with only one query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: The answer seem to be in the question title - so what problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.*, b.* 
From post a 
  left join post_meta b on (a.id = b.id and b.meta_key='x')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from post 
  left join 
  post_meta 
where isNull(post_meta.meta_value) 
      or 
      post_meta.meta_value ="x"
```

I haven't done much sql for a while, but I know it is possible. I think it was querying isNull on any value of the table that you are left joining.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from posts p
   left outer join post_meta pm on p.id=pm.post_id and pm.meta_key='x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
    select * from post 
    LEFT JOIN post_meta on post.id = post_meta.post_id where post_meta.x='x'

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
SELECT * FROM post,post_meta WHERE post.id=post_meta.post_id , post_meta.id="x";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.*, post_meta.* 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN post_meta 
ON posts.id = post_meta.post_id WHERE post_meta.meta_value is null OR
post_meta.meta_value = 'x'
```

Since you want all the posts from posts table whose corresponding meta_value in post_meta table is either 'x' or meta_value doesn't exists, this should work.